# code signature in (/xxxxx) not valid for use in process using Library Validation

Tags: macos, validation, codesign

I'm trying to build proxychains with xcode 8. When I run a program I got:

```
/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/proxychains-ng/4.11/lib/libproxychains4.dylib: code signing blocked mmap() of '/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/proxychains-ng/4.11/lib/libproxychains4.dylib'
```

When I signed the program and library:

```
codesign -s "Mac Developer: xxxx" `which proxychains` 
codesign -s "Mac Developer: xxxx" /usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/proxychains-ng/4.11/lib/libproxychains4.dylib
```

No errors, but when I run it again, it says

```
/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/proxychains-ng/4.11/lib/libproxychains4.dylib: code signature in (/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/proxychains-ng/4.11/lib/libproxychains4.dylib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapping process is a platform binary, but mapped file is not
```

What should I do now? Do I need some sort of entitlements?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you will need to build it with Xcode version 7.x. So, try to uninstall it with `brew uninstall proxychains-ng` (if using homebrew). Then you will need to select Xcode version 7 with `xcode-select` and finish by re-installing proxychains with `brew install proxychains-ng`. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem and solved it using code sign

I just codesign all errors.

```
codesign -f -s "Mac Developer: YOURDEVELOPEREMAIL" /usr/local/opt/*/lib/*.dylib
```